# How to add www to my domain and subdomain url

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I want to add www to my all sub domain urls.

For example I want to convert url `https://sub.mydomain.com` to `https://www.sub.mydomain.com`. Is this possible with htaccess ?

Currently I get an error when I add www before the sub domain

```
Error: Requested page cannot be loaded. 
Details: locale/www/labels.php not found.
```

Comment: I assume that it should instead be `locale/sub/labels.php`?

Comment: I have fixed the English.  Please post your attempts at changing the htaccess, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Rewrite_Engine (mod_rewrite) on your server, you can use it following way for redirecting of all visitors from URL without "www." to URL with "www." (you can add these lines in the .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But first of all you need to fix this error message (i.e. support showing of right pages on URLs with "www."). To do it you need to configre your server properly. But we don't know anything about configuration of your server, so can't help you. Please extend your question.